# Is there any builtin function to convert scientific notation number to a normal float number?

Tags: python

There a `data.txt`:

```
1571040600: 1.9673150889e+03 2.3919535556e+03
1571040900: 1.2449858889e+03 1.5374418444e+03
1571041200: 1.0841996556e+03 1.3565952667e+03
1571041500: 9.5094722222e+02 1.1993240000e+03
1571041800: 1.4359398000e+03 1.7860326778e+03
1571042100: 1.0457769889e+03 1.3188025444e+03
1571042400: 8.2156277372e+02 1.0441558276e+03
1571042700: 6.0619294014e+02 7.7817031248e+02
...
```

I am very understand the `1.9673150889e+03` means `1.967315088 * 10^3`, 
but is there a builtin method to convert this type number to a float number in general?

```
1.9673150889e+03 -> 1967.3150889
```

Comment: Do you mean to **print** it in the desired format? There is no conversion between float in scientific notation and in "normal float number", it's just a formatting difference

Comment: From that one, answer would be `f'{a:.20f}'` where `a` is your number.

Comment: From what I understand he wants to convert the string '1.9673150889e+03' to float. 
In Python you can do this: 
my_float = float('1.9673150889e+03')